# centering jButton horizontally in relation to JTable with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I hava a `JTable` and I have placed 3 `JButton`s below it. I've manage to put the left button on the left corner and the right button on the right corner but I can't figure out how to place the middle button in the center. I have tried using `.weightx` and `.anchor` without any results.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class AccessView extends JPanel{
  String[] columnNames = {"Date","Time","Type of access"};
  DefaultTableModel tableModel;
  JTable tAccesses;
  JScrollPane scrollPane;
  JButton bAdd, bMod, bDel;

  public AccessView(){
    createGUI();
  }

   public void createGUI(){
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Accesses"));
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    bAdd = new JButton("Add");
    bMod = new JButton("Mod");
    bDel = new JButton("Del");

    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(25,columnNames.length);
    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);   
    tAccesses = new JTable(tableModel);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tAccesses);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    this.add(scrollPane, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    this.add(bAdd, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    this.add(bMod, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
    this.add(bDel, c);
  }  
}
```

Comment: You can introduce an additional `JPanel` for the buttons and provide a separate `LayoutManager` to it. Unfortunately I don't know if there's a built-in one to exactly fulfill your needs.

Comment: @Izruo i've tried using another JPanel with BoxLayout for the JButtons. Unfortunately, all i get is to center  the 3 buttons since that JPanel doesn't match the size of the JScrollPane. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, you can use another `JPanel` for the 3 `JButton`s.

Using `BoxLayout` for `JPanel` which will contain the 3 `JButton`s and [`Box.createHorizontalGlue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createHorizontalGlue--) between each `JButton` you can get the following output:

[image]

In this case:

1. Create a new `JPanel`

   ```
   JPanel buttonsPane;
   ```
2. Initialize it and set its layout to `BoxLayout`

   ```
   buttonsPane = new JPanel();
   buttonsPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
   ```
3. Add the buttons along with `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` between them:

   ```
   buttonsPane.add(bAdd);
   buttonsPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
   buttonsPane.add(bMod);
   buttonsPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
   buttonsPane.add(bDel);
   ```
4. Add the `buttonsPane` to your `JFrame`'s `SOUTH` alignment (or add it along with your current `JPanel` and edit its constraints (I used the former)):

   ```
   frame.add(this);
   frame.add(buttonsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   ```

---

Another way you could achieve a similar result (as per @MadProgrammer comment below) would be changing your constraints and adding "empty" components between your `JButton`s:

```
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.weightx = 1;
this.add(bAdd, c);

c.gridx = 1;
this.add(new JLabel(""), c); //Empty component just for the extra space

c.gridx = 2;
this.add(bMod, c);

c.gridx = 3;
this.add(new JLabel(""), c); //Empty component just for the extra space

c.gridx = 4;
this.add(bDel, c);
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Personally, I'd use `GridBagLayout` for the `buttonsPane`, but that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I accept suggestions, I always learn something new, could I know the reason behind your preference? In this case it was the easiest way I could think of

Comment: @Frakcool. Thank you for your answer. I also had to change the layout of the extended JPanel to BoxLayout. For some reason, despite making the changes you suggested, it wouldn't work with the GridBagLayout.

Comment: @potato See the updated answer :) It could work as well without creating a new `JPanel` just for the `JButton`s

Comment: @Frakcool Persoanlly, I prefer the look of the layout as all the buttons would be laid out side by side in the centre of the panel, this provides a better user experience (IMHO) as all three actions are laid out close together, they become "grouped".  If I was doing a navigation layout, then what you have would be suitable for "previous"/"next" style look and feel.  Consider also, if you had some other "unlike" actions.  You could use different white space to differentiate between the groups of actions - again, this is just all personal opinion ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh I see, well I've just worked professionally with Swing once in my final project for school which is now being used for some reports, etc. But having someone experienced with it like you, now I get what you mean, it's just for the user experience not for maintenance purposes... And after trying it in the updated answer I agree, it looks better as if it belongs to the table above and not as a separate module :) Thanks for that

Comment: @Frakcool Regrettably, a lot of UI design comes down to "personal preference" :P

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments and the advice. I will do as suggested and center the buttons for a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this:

- Since you extends `JPanel` and have `GridBagLayout` for the whole
  panel, you could just add additional row for buttons. It looks like
  table layout in Web - and it actually is. There are pro and contras
  with table layout. The main disadvantage is it's hard to mantain in a  long-term project. In particular, you can't re-use buttons elsewhere.
- You could create additional panel with buttons, as @Izruo suggested. The key feature is you could easily move this panel from bottom to left of your grid, add to another similar panel/menu etc. The simplest [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) would be enough. After you created a `ButtonPanel`, you could

  - add it to your grid. It's slightly better than table-only layout
  - create *CompositePanel* which will contain both *GridPanel* and *ButtonPanel*

Studying [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) I noticed that the last option is preferable. From my personal experience, it's a best practice